# Const procedure in C++, weird error in Visual Studio C++ 2010?

Tags: c++, visual-c++-2010

```
class a{
public:
    int b;
    static int c;
    virtual void mod() const
    {
        c=4;
    }

};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  a bi;

  return 0;
}
```

Look at this ... After compiling it using Visual Studio C++ 2010 compiler, I get...

> cpplearningconsole.obj : error
>   LNK2001: unresolved external symbol
>   "public: static int a::c" (?c@a@@2HA)

I guess this is a compiler bug.
For me, the real question is. Should mod be able to modify c variable if it is const?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a compiler bug... You have declared the static member `c`, but not defined it anywhere.

Comment: `mod` can be `const` and change the value of `c`, because `c` isn't a member of the instance (because it's static) that `mod` is called on, so the instance doesn't change.

Comment: mod is defined in the class, as well as b, Why not c? Where is the logic in this?

Comment: `b` is a normal member of the class, hence is constructed when instances of the class are. There is no need to reserve storage for it. `mod` is a function. You have provided a body for the function within the class, so you have defined it. If you just had `virtual void mod() const;`, instead of the body, you would get a similar link error because of the missing function (you may have to call the function before the linker would notice it's missing).

Comment: @Aftershock: Rule 1: it is *never* a compiler bug. Rule 2: (Experts only) it is *never* a compiler bug. (Though I admit VS has some bugs, you are very very very unlikely to ever tumble on one)

Comment: mantra otherwise known as ["Select isn't broken"](http://pragprog.com/the-pragmatic-programmer/extracts/tips)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have just *declared* the static variable in the class definition, you need to *define* it in the by doing `int a::c = 0;`.

Comment: Indeed, and the error does not have anything to do with the member function being `const`, and it's ofcourse not a compiler bug.

Answer (score 3):

This:

> cpplearningconsole.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int a::c" (?c@a@@2HA)

Isn't a compiler message, it's a linker message.  You're getting it, because although you have declared the member `c`, you haven't defined it.  Static members need to be defined in only one source file, in order for them to be created.  Something like:

```
int a::c = 0;
```

As for your second question, declaring a function as `const`, states that it doesn't modify the object that it's being called on.  You `mod` function doesn't modify the object, it modifies the static member.  Which is why you don't get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the correct definition for your variable member, in the class you only have the declaration. In your cpp or just after the class declaration (outside of it) add:

`int a::c = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

To answer your other question:

`c` is a public static member of your class. **Anyone** can change its value, so why not `mod()`?